# Inverse of Locator?

Tags: ios5, sphero-api

I know it's possible to tell where the Sphero is using Locator.  Is it possible therefore to tell where the phone is in relation to the Sphero?  Which framework should I be looking at on the ios device side?

Comment: What have you looked at or tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could instruct the user of the app to stand over the Sphero and press a button, if you zero the locator at this point and the user stands still you could assume the user is at 0,0.

Comment: Well, I want the Sphero to be aware of the user's location (e.g., where his iOS device is), so the Sphero has to have some way of telling where the device is, and that's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: Also, the user should be able to move around with the iOS device.